second array of qustions doesnt pop up in question/options menu
I have sections on my html file, identified by an ID, under them are a review set of questions that every answer goes to the next. I can get the first one to work, but when I use the code but change the variable names for the same page, it doesnt work. no matter if I call iterate first or iterate2 first, only iterate works
home.html - used to display right and wrong count of answers
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- MY Script JS -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h5>Right Answers:</h5>
    <p id="outputright"></p>

    <h5>Wrong Answers:</h5>
    <p id="outputwrong"></p>

    <p>
        <iframe id="iframe" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" src="iframe.html" height="300" width="300"></iframe>
    </p>
</body>

</html>

script.js - used to increment the count via the answers in the iframe
// Define variables to store counts
let rtemp = 0;
let wtemp = 0;

// Function to update the right count in the parent document
function updateValueRight(plusR) {
    // Update the right count by adding the provided value
    rtemp += plusR;
    // Display the updated right count
    const rightEl = document.getElementById('outputright');
    rightEl.innerText = rtemp;
}

// Function to update the wrong count in the parent document
function updateValueWrong(plusW) {
    // Update the wrong count by adding the provided value
    wtemp += plusW;
    // Display the updated wrong count
    const wrongEl = document.getElementById('outputwrong');
    wrongEl.innerText = wtemp;
}

// Initialization code when the DOM is ready
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Get elements displaying the counts
    const rightEl = document.getElementById('outputright');
    const wrongEl = document.getElementById('outputwrong');

    // Display default counts
    rightEl.innerText = rtemp;
    wrongEl.innerText = wtemp;
    
    /* set iframe to display certain section of Funfacts.html HAS to be out of the WindDOM*/
    function setURL(url){
        document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
    }
});

iframe.html - where the questions answer gets recorded (increments accordingly) and it goes through an array of questions
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Are you cool?</p>
    <button id="right" onclick="right()">Yes</button>
    <button id="wrong" onclick="wrong()">No</button>
    <button class="btn">Maybe</button>

    <article>
      <section id="webcam"><h3><b>How's my coffee?</b></h3>
        <p>webcam article info</p> 
    </article>
    
    <button id="webcamRev">Review</button>
    <div class="review">
        <div class="question-container" id="question1">
          <h1>Question goes here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="option-container">
          <button type="button" class="option next" id="op11">Option 1</button>
          <button type="button" class="option next" id="op12">Option 2</button>
          <button type="button" class="option next" id="op13">Option 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    
    <article>
        <section id="virus"><h3><b>First Computer <i>'Virus'</i></b></h3> </section>
        <p>virus article info</p> 
    </article>
    <button id="virusRev">Review</button>

    <div class="review">
        <div class="question-container" id="question">
          <h1>Question goes here</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="option-container">
          <button type="button" class="option next" id="op1">Option 1</button>
          <button type="button" class="option next" id="op2">Option 2</button>
          <button type="button" class="option next" id="op3">Option 3</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    
  
        
    <!-- Script to call functions -->
    <script src="iscript.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

iframe script iscript.js - the array of questions and 'next question' code
// Function to call the parent function to increment the right count
function right() {
    // Call the parent function and pass the incremented value
    window.parent.updateValueRight(1); // Increment by 1
}

// Function to call the parent function to increment the wrong count
function wrong() {
    // Call the parent function and pass the incremented value
    window.parent.updateValueWrong(1); // Increment by 1
}


// Initialization code when the DOM is ready
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

const virusQue = [
  {
    id: 1,
    q: "Question?",
    a: ["one", "two","three"],
    correctAnswerIndex: 2 // Index of the correct answer 
    },
  {
    id: 2,
    q: "question two",
    a: ["que one", "que two","que three" ],
    correctAnswerIndex: 1 // Index of the correct answer 
    },
  {
    id: 3,
    q: "question 3",
    a: ["one que", "two que","three que"],
    correctAnswerIndex: 3 // Index of the correct answer 

    },
];
//  a:["","",""],
const webcamQue = [
    {
      id: 1,
      q: "lol question",
      a: ["lol one", "lol two","lol three"],
      correctAnswerIndex: 2 // Index of the correct answer 
      },
    {
      id: 2,
      q: "pizza",
      a: ["pepperoni", "cheese","none"],
      correctAnswerIndex: 1 // Index of the correct answer 
      },
    {
      id: 3,
      q: "apple",
      a: ["no strawberry","yes with honey", "blueberries 4life"],
      correctAnswerIndex: 3 // Index of the correct answer 
  
      },
  ];
  
  
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const question1 = document.getElementById("question1");
let id = 0; // Initialize id here
let id2 = 0; // Initialize id here

function iterate(id) {
    console.log("Inside iterate function. ID:", id);

    // Getting the options
    const op1 = document.getElementById("op1");
    const op2 = document.getElementById("op2");
    const op3 = document.getElementById("op3");

    // Providing option text
    op1.innerText = virusQue[id].a[0]; // Set text of option 1 button
    op2.innerText = virusQue[id].a[1]; // Set text of option 2 button
    op3.innerText = virusQue[id].a[2]; // Set text of option 3 button

    // Setting the question text
    question.innerText = virusQue[id].q;
}


function iterate2(id2) {
  console.log("Inside iterate2 function. ID:", id2);

  // Getting the options
  const op1 = document.getElementById("op11");
  const op2 = document.getElementById("op12");
  const op3 = document.getElementById("op13");

  // Providing option text
  op1.innerText = webcamQue[id2].a[0]; // Set text of option 1 button
  op2.innerText = webcamQue[id2].a[1]; // Set text of option 2 button
  op3.innerText = webcamQue[id2].a[2]; // Set text of option 3 button

  // Setting the question text
  question1.innerText = webcamQue[id2].q;
}


iterate2(id2);
iterate(id);

// Event listener for all buttons with class 'option.next'
const optionButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.option.next');

optionButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const selectedOptionIndex = parseInt(button.id.slice(-1)); // Extracts the number from the button ID
    const section = button.dataset.section; // Get the section from the data-section attribute
    let correctAnswerIndex;

    // Determine the correct array based on the section
    if (section === "virus") {
      correctAnswerIndex = virusQue[id].correctAnswerIndex; // Get the correct answer index for the current virus question
    } else if (section === "webcam") {
      correctAnswerIndex = webcamQue[id2].correctAnswerIndex; // Get the correct answer index for the current webcam question
    }

    // Right answer!
    if (selectedOptionIndex === correctAnswerIndex) {
      right();
    } else {  // Wrong answer!
      wrong();
    }

    // Increment to the next question
    if (section === "virus" && id < virusQue.length - 1) { // Check if it's the virus section and id is within the bounds
      id++; // Increment id
      iterate(id); // Update the page with the next virus question
    } else if (section === "webcam" && id2 < webcamQue.length - 1) { // Check if it's the webcam section and id2 is within the bounds
      id2++; // Increment id2
      iterate2(id2); // Update the page with the next webcam question
    } else {
      // Mark the test as finished
      if (section === "virus") {
        question.innerText = "Congratulations. You have finished the virus review";
      } else if (section === "webcam") {
        question1.innerText = "Congratulations. You have finished the webcam review";
      }
    }
  });
});
});

This is as simple as I can make it and it still work to show my trouble having two questions at the same time. the second question queue doesn't fill like the first question queue but still registers as its incrementing for iterate() the original not iterate2()

Please show minimal reproducible example (ie runnable code) that shows your problem

@derpirscher I have included the runnable code example. I tried to simplify it more but it stops working
